Any flight ticket booking option which cheapest in india?
I need to book flight a ticket to Bangkok for my family, looking for the cheapest platform to book it.


There is no such thing as a single "cheapest platform". Flight prices are complicated, vary unpredictable with many different factors.
You can use a "flight search" engines to hone in on a good options that fit your specific needs (exact airports, date range, number of tickets). Examples are Google Flights, Skyscanner, ITA Matrix, etc.
Most airlines these days make a lot of money with "ancillary fees" , i.e. extra money you pay for luggage, seat reservations or selection, food, etc. You need to assess this any prospective booking for your specific needs.
Once you find a flight you should always book directly with the airlines if any possible. While some online travel agencies can be a few dollars cheaper, there is very high risk of a customer service nightmare it any is required (changes, modifications, cancellations, rebooking, rerouting, etc.)


ITA Matrix works best for flights involving US in my experience, so India to Thailand will benefit least from it.

@ave: what better engines do you suggest ?

Skyscanner and Google Flights should do nicely.
